# Compute $\int_{\gamma}|z-1||dz|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb C$ be given by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. Compute $\int_{\gamma}|z-1||dz|$.

$\int_{\gamma}|z-1||dz|=\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{it}-1|d|\gamma|$ where $|\gamma|$ is the variation of $\gamma$ from $0$ to $t$.

I am not sure how to deal with the $|d\gamma|$.

Does $\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{it}-1|d|\gamma|=\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{it}-1||ie^{it}|dt$ holds? Could anyone kindly help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that, by Euler's identity $$\left|i e^{it} \right| = \left|e^{it} \right| = \left| \cos{(t)} +i\sin{(t)} \right| = \sqrt{\cos^2{(t)} +\sin^2{(t)}} = 1.$$ Hence $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \left| e^{it} - 1 \right| \left| \gamma ' (t) \right| dt = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \left| e^{it} - 1 \right| dt.$$

We use Euler's identity a second time to evaluate the modulus in the integrand. One has

\begin{align*}
\left| e^{it} - 1 \right| 
& = \left| \cos{(t)} + i\sin{(t)} - 1 \right|  = \left| (\cos{(t)} - 1) + i\sin{(t)} \right|\\\\
& =\sqrt{(\cos{(t)} - 1)^2 + sin^2{(t)}} = \sqrt{(\cos^2{(t)} + sin^2{(t)} + 1 - 2\cos{(t)}}\\\\
&= \sqrt{1 + 1 - 2\cos{(t)}} = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos{(t)}}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, the final integral is $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \left| e^{it} - 1 \right| dt = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sqrt{2 - 2\cos{(t)}} dt.$$

This is an elementary integral. Using the appropriate substitution you should get $8$.

Comment: I don't think we need $2\pi$ here. Since $|\gamma'(t)|=1|$, the integral is just $\int_0^{2\pi}|e^{it}-1|dt$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I edited the answer with the corrected version. The integral is therefore equal to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $|dz| = |\gamma'(t)|\,dt$, so you're on the right track.